# Is it possible to convert 3D Matlab figure into .mat?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, nifti

Actually I have .fig file and want to convert it into nifti file (.nii), then I found make_nii function which request a .mat file.

Comment: No. A `.fig` file is purely a graphical representation of data and not data itself. You would need to save the 3D data used to generate the figure into a .mat file and load *that*

Comment: I want to repeat what Suever said. The image plotted is **not your data**. Its a plot of your data. Save the data.